# Controller doesn't work

Tags: controllers, module, configuration

Modifying an *existing, **functioning*** module, so assume the prerequisite setup code is fine. Adding to /app/code/local/Company/MyModule/etc/config.xml within `<frontend/>`:

```
        <routers>
            <mymodule>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Company_MyModule</module>
                    <frontName>mymodule</frontName>
                </args>
            </mymodule>
       </routers>
```

Created /app/code/local/Company/MyModule/controllers/IndexControlller.php:

```
<?php
    class Company_MyModule_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action {
        public function IndexAction() {
            die('hello, world');
        }
    }
```

Going to the expected address (www.company.com/mymodule) returns a 404 response.

Comment: Did you clear cache?

Comment: Caching is disabled. I deleted it anyway. No change.

Comment: Can you add your entire config.xml

Comment: Is there something in particular you're looking for in it? There's no duplicate `<frontend/>` and the rest of the module works as expected. I just can't get the controller to work. In fact, I've never been able to get *any* controllers to work that I've made.

Comment: Try create a module with only 'Need Frontend Page' at http://www.silksoftware.com/magento-module-creator/#.VDLbDNPF-QM ... if this don't then you may have a module that preventing it

Comment: It doesn't work. I've even tried implementing it in one of my test environments where the only custom code is stuff I've written. Controllers simply don't appear to work. I've even changed the name of `indexAction` to `IndexAction` as per the generated file.

Comment: Did you add /etc/modules/ file?

Comment: Try disable all your custom modules (from /etc/modules/) and try again.. If that work then try enable them one by one

Comment: I've emphasized the part I think is being missed here.

Comment: put full config.xml..

Comment: Am I being trolled? I've shown you all that's relevant.

Comment: Do you have the compilation enabled? If so, then disable it.

Comment: Compilation was already disabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that the store code was not present in the URL. It was also set to "Yes" under System > Configuration > Web > Url Options > Add Store Code to Urls.

Answer (score 0):

Enable your Module
app\etc\modules\Company_MyModule.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <Company_MyModule>
      <active>true</active>
      <codePool>local</codePool>
      <version>0.1.0</version>
    </Company_MyModule>
  </modules>
</config>
```

app\code\local\Company\MyModule\etc\config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <Company_MyModule>
      <version>0.1.0</version>
    </Company_MyModule>
  </modules>
  <frontend>
    <routers>
      <mymodule>
        <use>standard</use>
          <args>
            <module>Company_MyModule</module>
            <frontName>mymodule</frontName>
          </args>
      </mymodule>
    </routers>
        <layout>
          <updates>
            <mymodule>
              <file>mymodule.xml</file>
            </mymodule>
          </updates>
        </layout>
  </frontend>
  <global>
    <helpers>
      <mymodule>
        <class>Company_MyModule_Helper</class>
      </mymodule>
    </helpers>
    <blocks>
      <mymodule>
        <class>Company_MyModule_Block</class>
      </mymodule>
    </blocks>
  </global>
</config>
```

app\code\local\Company\MyModule\controllers\IndexController.php

```
<?php
class Company_MyModule_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action{
    public function IndexAction() {      
      $this->loadLayout();    
      $this->renderLayout();      
    }
}
```

app\code\local\Company\MyModule\Helper\Data.php

```
<?php
class Company_MyModule_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract
{
}
```

You can define layout Block in app\design\frontend\base\default\layout\mymodule.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>   
<layout version="0.1.0">   
  <mymodule_index_index>   
    <reference name="root">   
      <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/1column.phtml</template></action>   
    </reference>   
    <reference name="content">   

    </reference>   
  </mymodule_index_index>   
</layout>
```

Comment: The module already has prerequisite information (i.e. Company_MyModule.xml), as well as configured Models and a Helper at Helper\Data.php. The controller does not need to perform any layout duties whatsoever; its only purpose will be to serve text data as a response to an AJAX script.

Comment: Are you make sure your permission to Module files

Comment: Yes, it's a local install in Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout these things.

1. I can see an error in your `index` action. It should be `index`, instead of `Index`. ie

   ```
   public function indexAction() 
   {
       die ('hello, world');
   }
   ```
2. Make sure your module is active. For this go to

   ```
   System  >  Configuration  >  Advanced
   ```

and check whether module is available over there.

3. Check all of your file permissions. Make it has 777 permission
4. Try out `www.domain.com/index.php/mydomain`

### Edit

5. I can see another error in your controller file. The class name should be `Company_MyModule_IndexController` instead of `Company_MyModule_indexController`.
6. If none of the above method exists, then checkout log files. You may see some errors there. If exists, please put add it with your question

Comment: 1. I thought so. The generated code from a comments suggested it be capitalized, so I tried that. Will revert to `indexAction`.
2. It's active.
3. Testing on a local install on Windows. I totally have permission.
4. Tried that method and several others.

Comment: removed cache ?

Comment: I have updated answer. Please go through it

Comment: Caching is disabled. Fixed capitalization; no dice. There are also no errors being logged.

Answer (score 0):

1. Check "allow symlink" in database
2. Check if you have store in your url
3. Check module config and folder - local or community
4. Check spelling, folder structure, folder and file names, camelcase and underscores
5. Check if folder/files are accessible (exists and has right permissions) for webserver